# How do I match lomb-scargle and FFT plots of same dataset?

Tags: python, fft, units-of-measurement, psd

I am doing some work, comparing the interpolated fft of the concentrations of some gases over a period, of which is unevenly sampled, with the lomb-scargle periodogram of the same data. I am using scipy's fft function to calculate the fourier transform and then squaring the modulus of this to give what I believe to be the power spectral density, in units of parts per billion(ppb) squared.

I can get the lomb-scargle plot to match almost the exact pattern as the FFT but never the same scale of magnitude, the FFT power spectral density always is higher, even though I thought the lomb-scargle power was power spectral density.  Now the lomb code I am using:http://www.astropython.org/snippet/2010/9/Fast-Lomb-Scargle-algorithm, normalises the dataset taking away the average and dividing by 2 times the variance from the data, therefore I have normalised the FFT data in the same manner, but still the magnitudes do not match.

Therefore I did some more research and found that the normalised lomb-scargle power could unitless and therefore I cannot the plots match. This leads me to the 2 questions:

1. What units (if any) are the power spectral density of a normalised lim-scargle perioogram in?
2. How would I proceed to match my fft plot with my lomb-scargle plot, in terms of magnitude and pattern?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The squared modulus of the Fourier transform of a series is defined as the ***energy spectral density*** (ESD).  You need to divide the ESD by the length of the series to convert to an estimate of ***power spectral density*** (PSD).

### Units

The units of a PSD are [units]**2/[frequency] where [units] represents the units of your original series.

### Normalization

To check for proper normalization, one can numerically integrate the PSD of a white noise (with known variance).  If the integrated spectrum equals the variance of the series, the normalization is correct.  A factor of 2 (too low) is not incorrect, though, and may indicate the PSD is normalized to be *double-sided*; in that case, just multiply by 2 and you have a properly normalized, single-sided PSD.

Using numpy, the [randn](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.7.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html) function generates pseudo-random numbers that are Gaussian distributed.  For example

```
10 * np.random.randn(1, 100)
```

produces a 1-by-100 array with mean=0 and variance=100.  If the sampling frequency is, say, 1-Hz, the *single-sided* PSD will theoretically be flat at 200 units**2/Hz, from [0,0.5] Hz; the integrated spectrum would thus be 10, equaling the variance of the series.

*Update*

I modified the example included in the python code you linked to demonstrate the normalization for a normally distributed series of length 20, with variance 1, and sampling frequency 10:

```
import numpy
import lomb
numpy.random.seed(999)
nd = 20
fs = 10
x = numpy.arange(nd)
y = numpy.random.randn(nd)
fx, fy, nout, jmax, prob = lomb.fasper(x, y, 1., fs)
fNy = fx[-1]
fy = fy/fs
Si = numpy.mean(fy)*fNy
print fNy, Si, Si*2
```

This gives, for me:

```
5.26315789474 0.482185882163 0.964371764327
```

which shows you a few things:

1. The "Nyquist" frequency asked for is actually the sampling frequency.
2. The result needs to be divided by the sampling frequency.
3. The output is normalized for a double-sided PSD, so multiplying by 2 makes the integrated spectrum nearly 1.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much, this has been of great help to me. However, I have calculated the outputted mean, variance and integration of the lomb periodograms, from the lomb code I have been using. The mean is 1.00384639869, variance is 1743.88416724, and integrated spectrum = 11.9433669652. I am struggling to understand what is going on, or if the data is at all normalised? (even if it says so in the code).

Comment: Are you using a white noise series? What is the variance? What is the sampling frequency?  Without more information (e.g. code) I can't really help.

Comment: I added an example; hopefully it will help you find the source of your normalization discrepancy.  Good luck.

Comment: A huge thank you, everything is perfectly normalised and matching up now. Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

In the time since this question was asked and answered, the AstroPy project has gained a Lomb-Scargle method, and this question is addressed in the documentation: http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/stats/lombscargle.html#psd-normalization-unnormalized

In brief, you can compute a Fourier periodogram and compare it to the astropy Lomb-Scargle periodogram as follows

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.stats import LombScargle

def fourier_periodogram(t, y):
    N = len(t)
    frequency = np.fft.fftfreq(N, t[1] - t[0])
    y_fft = np.fft.fft(y)
    positive = (frequency > 0)
    return frequency[positive], (1. / N) * abs(y_fft[positive]) ** 2

t = np.arange(100)
y = np.random.randn(100)
frequency, PSD_fourier = fourier_periodogram(t, y)
PSD_LS = LombScargle(t, y).power(frequency, normalization='psd')

np.allclose(PSD_fourier, PSD_LS)
# True
```

Since AstroPy is a common tool used in astronomy, I thought this might be more useful than an answer based on the code snippet mentioned above.